# perl regex character classes

Tags: regex, perl

i'm having trouble regex grouping in perl.

of course this is a much larger problem but it's the same concept i'm dealing with. thank you all in advance for your comments and ideas.

the regex below should only care about this portion of the string to make a decision.

> doctor_who:ee
>
> doctor_who:ep
>
> doctor_who:ex

but not

> doctor_who:eeh

code:

```
$str = "doctor_who:ee123ABC451234.123"; #match
$str = "doctor_who:ep123YXZ451234.123"; #match
$str = "doctor_who:ex123451234.123"; #match
$str = "doctor_who:eeh1234LMNOP51234.123";  ##should not match
$str = "doctor_who:abc12341234.123";  ##should not match

$regex = "doctor_who:e[e|p|x]"; #--->problem, what to add/remove?

if ($str =~ m/$regex/){
   print "match!";
}
else {
   print "not matched\n";
}
```

Comment: Note: `[e|p|x]` is the same thing as `[epx|]`; it matches any of those four characters. You meant to use `[epx]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's trivial with a negative lookahead zero-width assertion. This assumes the only thing you don't want to match specifically is `doctor_who:eeh*`:

```
/doctor_who:e(?!eh)[epx]/
```

In the above example, as long as we match `doctor_who:e`, we will trigger the lookahead on every match. We can gain efficiency by only using it if absolutely necessary, as noted in the comments by @ikegami:

```
/doctor_who:e(?:[px]|e(?!h))/
```

What that'll do is put off the lookahead unless the second char after the `:` is not `p` or `x`, and then only if that char is `e`.

The second example shown in the comments doesn't use lookarounds at all:

```
/doctor_who:e(?:[px]|e[^h])/
```

Comment: Lookarounds are rather expensive, so I'd write it as `/doctor_who:e(?:[px]|e(?!h))/` or even `/doctor_who:e(?:[px]|e(?:[^h]|\z))/`. In practice, it might be possible to use `[^h]` instead of `(?:[^h]|\z)`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not matching at the end of the string I think you would need two regexes.

```
$regex = "doctor_who:e[epx]"; # match
$not_regex "doctor_who:e[epx][a-z]"; #-do not match
```

Then just do

```
if( $string =~ $regex and $string !~ $not_regex ){}
```

Comment: he's not trying to match at the end of the string. that'll never match

Answer (score 1):

You can do this two ways and you combined the two.

Use a character class:

```
$regex = 'doctor_who:e[epx]';
```

Use an alternation:

```
$regex = 'doctor_who:e(e|p|x)';
```

These provide the positive match, but they need something else to reject the `eeh` match.

But, is `eeh` the *only* match to reject? That's the only one you mentioned, but, would you prefer something more general, such as any *a-z* character? (e.g.) What about `eec`? Should it match or be rejected?

From the examples, `ee1` matches. Is that because `1` is *not* `h` or because it's a digit?

It isn't totally clear [to me, at least] what the best, most succinct regex should be, because there are some loopholes in the examples. So, here are some regexes based on assumptions I've made as to what you'd really like.

So, if `eeh` is the only rejection, add:

```
$regex .= '[^h]';
```

If you'd like a broader rejection:

```
$regex .= '[^a-z]';
```

Or, perhaps, you'd only like to match on numeric:

```
$regex .= '[0-9]';
```

*Side note:* This answer has been edited to reflect the comments below

Comment: OP is not trying to match at the end of the string. If you were to do it this way, you'd have to substr the string at a specific length (or otherwise extract only the portion you want), then match with $

Comment: that wont work either. A word boundary is whitespace, and there's no whitespace after what he's trying to hit :)

Comment: see my previous comment

Comment: @stevieb I've been working on it. From the top it would seem the rejection is [only] `eeh` if the first two chars match. But, should `eec` also fail [yet `ee1` matches]? At this point, to me, the intent/criterion isn't clear even with the examples given

Comment: `$regex .= '[^h]';` won't allow `:eph` or `:exh` to match, along with `:eeh`